# Rationalizing $\frac{\sqrt{1+\cos x}+\sqrt{1-\cos x}}{\sqrt{1+\cos x}-\sqrt{1-\cos x}}$ in two ways gives different answers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, rationalising-denominator

I have a doubt see when we rationalize denominator of expression $$\frac{\sqrt{1+\cos x}+\sqrt{1-\cos x}}{\sqrt{1+\cos x}- \sqrt{1-\cos x}}$$
we get answer $$\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}$$ but when we rationalize numerator we get
$$\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}$$
How is this possible, because rationalizing means just multiplying by $1$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics, check out [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation) and [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),

Comment: Also as to your actual question, I would encourage you to check your algebra for rationalizing the numerator. You should at first get a result that will still look different from rationalizing the denominator, but you can then try to prove that the two expressions are in fact equal.

Comment: Actually, they are both correct, but not for the same values of $x$. Which also means they are both only partly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting $a$ for $\cos x$,
you have
(notice the MathJax)

$\dfrac{\sqrt{1+a}+\sqrt{1-a}}{\sqrt{1+a}-\sqrt{1-a}}
$

I now do the rationalizing
(using
$(u+v)(u-v)=u^2-v^2)$
and later substitute
$a = \cos(x)$
and use
$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1$.

I am doing this
in excruciating detail
so you can see
all the steps involved.
Once you understand these,
you should be able
to do this kind of thing
by yourself.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{\sqrt{1+a}+\sqrt{1-a}}{\sqrt{1+a}-\sqrt{1-a}}
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{1+a}+\sqrt{1-a}}{\sqrt{1+a}-\sqrt{1-a}}\dfrac{\sqrt{1+a}+\sqrt{1-a}}{\sqrt{1+a}+\sqrt{1-a}}\\
&=\dfrac{1+a+2\sqrt{1+a}\sqrt{1-a}+1-a}{(1+a)-(1-a)}\\
&=\dfrac{2+2\sqrt{(1+a)(1-a)}}{2a}\\
&=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}\\
&=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}}{\cos(x)}\\
&=\dfrac{1+\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\\
\end{array}
$

I will be glad to answer
any questions you may have.

Comment: Got it thankyou

Comment: $\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}=|\sin x|$, and when $|\sin(x)|=-\sin(x)$, we have:

$$\frac{1-\sin x }{\cos x}=\frac{1-\sin^2 x}{\cos x(1+\sin x)}=\frac{\cos}{1+\sin x}$$

So the OP is indeed almost right.

Answer (score 2):

You might have an error, check that at the end you should have that rationalazing the denominator you should have that $$\cfrac{1+\sin{x}}{\cos{x}},$$ and the numerator you should have that $$\cfrac{\cos{x}}{1-\sin{x}},$$ wich it´s always the same by $(\cos{x})^2+(\sin{x})^2=1$